# Using AI generators to ask questions to provoke thinking instead of giving answers?

Tags: artificial-intelligence, gpt-2, gpt-3

I have a use case that I want to use to help independent creators talk about their interests on Twitter using their experiences.

It goes like this:

You have an **interest** you want to talk about **Entrepreneurship**

You have an **experience** like **Pain**

Is there a way for an AI (like GPT) to generate prompts that uses these two words to create a list of open-ended questions that provoke thoughts such as these:

- If entrepreneurship wasn't painful, what would it look like?
- What do you know about entrepreneurship that is painful that starters should know?
- How can you lower the barrier to entrepreneurship so that it's a less painful opportunity for a person to take?

If so, how will it work, and what do I need to do?

I've explored Open AI's documentation on GPT-3, I'm unclear if it solves this problem of generating prompts.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should provide some samples so that the GPT-3 can see the pattern and produce a sensible response from your prompt.
For example, see the following screenshot from your case. Note that the bold text is my prompt. The regular text is the response from GPT-3. In that example, I was  "priming" the GPT-3 with relevant pattern: First line, the general description, then the Topics, followed by Questions. This should be enough for booting up your ideas and customizations.

[image: sample of prompt to generate questions from topics]

Comment: Do you have a clue about how to speed up the API waitlist process for GPT-3?

Comment: Thanks for the upvote! You can read the article here for the tips. https://www.flowrite.com/blog/how-we-got-access-to-gpt-3-in-5-days .